# No sound in headphones after upgrade to 15.10

Tags: sound, 15.10

I have problem, that there is absolutely no sound from headphones. When I upgraded to 15.10 the sound worked, but suddenly it stopped after system update. I have ThinkPad T440s laptop. Thanks.

Comment: Same for me on a ThinkPad W541.

Comment: i also have  this problem on my T440p